# I tried to change a part of a String with .charAt(i) in a forloop

Tags: java

```
for (int o = 0; o<gW.length;o++ ) {
 backToString.charAt(o) = gW[o];
}                   ^

error: unexpected type
```

i already changed the name of the int because there is another for loop but it didnt help

Comment: A String is immutable. And anyway, a method call can't be on the left side of an assignment operator.

Comment: If you want to replace characters then one way to do this would be to get a copy of the string's char array (`toCharArray()`), set the character there and construct a new string from the changed char array (`new String(changedCharArray)`).

Comment: You have to do this in two statements: char c = gW[o]; if (o < (gW.length - 1) {backToString = backToString.substring(0, o) + c + backToString(o);} else {backToString = backToString.substring(0, o) + c;}

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder. It may be what you need here.